# Potentiometer rated power and 16 LEDs

Tags: power, led, potentiometer

Using 5 mm through-hole LEDs, 4 in series and 4 in parallel, 3.3 V, 25 mA,  16 in total. Battery voltage is 12.9 V (car lead acid).

I want to control brightness using a carbon potentiometer 15 mm dia, 10 kΩ, rated power is around 250 mW to 350 mW. [image: It's a carbon pot](It's a carbon pot, not wire wound).

Is the rated power of the pot suitable?

How about using 100 mA SMD LEDs, 350 mW in the same 4X4 configuration?

Comment: Well considering you are using 13.2V of series leds with 12.9V (max, 12v nominal), your pot is probably fine enough.  Your not going to draw 100 mA because you are below the nominal voltage (3.3V at 25mA) so anything the pot will drop is minimal

Comment: A 10k pot is too much for led control. You want at worst a 50 or 100 ohm pot. At 20 ohms your not even going to see anything but the pin prick of light tbh.

Comment: 100 ohm 500 ohms is available but its non linear scale and is not ip rated

Comment: Boarderline XY question. A pot is ill-suited for this task. Run them all in series and get yourself a CC boost converter?

Comment: If you change LED arrangement to 2 x Vin = 24v /3 = 8.  So, an 8s2p, 8-serial by 2-series, a Joule Thief would work. Add a pull-down of perhaps 330 ohm, to get the NPN-base to turn off faster. Also add a diode (and zener) to prevent >5V of negative voltage on the base-emitter junction. Also add a resistor in series with the potentiometer so it doesn't burn out at low resistances. And don't forget capacitors on input and output, and inrush protection. After figuring out all this... *Then* you may finally select which pot you want to use. A 10K pot might work, but you may need a 100K.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to control brightness using a carbon potentiometer 15 mm dia, 10 kΩ, rated power is around 250 mW to 350 mW.

Maximum current the track in the pot can handle can be calculated from \$ P = I^2R \$. Rearranging we get
$$ I_{max} = \sqrt{\frac P R} = \sqrt {\frac {0.25}{10k}} = 5 \mathrm{mA} $$

Note that what's important is the power dissipation per unit length of resistance track. Don't think that you can turn the pot to 10% of the way and dissipate 0.25 W in that 10%. You can't. You could only dissipate 0.025 W on that portion of the resistance track.

The pot would not even support one series string of LEDs.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to my detailed answer to a duplicate question posted by the OP:

[LED brightness control with a potentiometer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/645354/led-brightness-control-with-a-potentiometer/645363?noredirect=1#comment1769949_645363)

What must be understood about using just a potentiometer (or rheostat) for LED brightness control, is that its power rating and resistance determine the maximum current it can safely handle. So the 10k device shown in the image might be 1 watt, that means that its maximum current is:

I = sqrt(P/R) = 10 mA

Also, there needs to be some "headroom" between the minimum supply voltage (in this case 12V) and the maximum voltage of the LED string for desired brightness (in this case limited by the 10mA maximum current). So for typical white LEDs with 3V forward voltage, only three can be connected in series, leaving 3 volts to be dropped by the potentiometer. 10 mA at 3V is a resistance of 300 ohms. For a 10k pot with 270 degrees of rotation, this resistance comprises only 8 degrees. To get 10% brightness at 1 mA, the shaft would be turned to get 3k resistance, or 80 degrees, and at minimum, you would have 300 uA, which is very dim.

However, adding a single transistor and a current limiting reference resistor, a practical circuit can be made:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo4IX4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the potentiometer set at 30%, the base of Q1 will be 3 volts, and the voltage on the emitter will be about 2.3 volts, corresponding to 46 mA through the LED string. The maximum current would be with the pot set at about 40%, which would cause Q1 to be saturated, with 3V on the emitter and 60 mA through the LEDs.

(edit) Here is an LTspice simulation that shows the effect of varying the 10k pot from 0 to 50%, with a 20 ohm resistor, and maximum current of 150 mA:

[image: LED String Brightness]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Joule Thief circuit to dim nicely and be quite flexible. I have worked up something that might serve as a starting point for doing what you want, and also learning more. Note that even though this is more complicated than what you are asking for, the version you are asking for is actually unrealistic, and won't work, as pointed out by the other answers. Please accept the answer by PStechPaul, as I think it is the best answer (and we do, after all, work for free, and work hard for the points, in addition).

Enjoy. (Source code at bottom. Copy and past into a file named *.asc like "Converter.asc", and open in LTSpice, which is free, and great for simulating Joule Thief circuits).

[image]

Source Code:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 2892 680
WIRE -608 -112 -720 -112
WIRE -416 -112 -608 -112
WIRE -160 -112 -240 -112
WIRE -64 -112 -96 -112
WIRE 32 -112 0 -112
WIRE 128 -112 96 -112
WIRE 224 -112 192 -112
WIRE 320 -112 288 -112
WIRE 416 -112 384 -112
WIRE 512 -112 480 -112
WIRE 624 -112 576 -112
WIRE -608 -96 -608 -112
WIRE -416 -96 -416 -112
WIRE -608 0 -608 -16
WIRE -416 32 -416 -16
WIRE -368 32 -416 32
WIRE -240 32 -240 -112
WIRE -240 32 -272 32
WIRE -352 48 -368 32
WIRE -288 48 -272 32
WIRE -192 48 -208 48
WIRE -176 48 -192 48
WIRE -416 64 -416 32
WIRE -240 80 -240 32
WIRE -208 80 -208 48
WIRE -208 80 -240 80
WIRE -160 80 -208 80
WIRE -80 80 -96 80
WIRE -64 80 -80 80
WIRE 32 80 0 80
WIRE 128 80 96 80
WIRE 224 80 192 80
WIRE 320 80 288 80
WIRE 416 80 384 80
WIRE 512 80 480 80
WIRE 624 80 624 -112
WIRE 624 80 576 80
WIRE -720 112 -720 -112
WIRE -688 112 -720 112
WIRE -672 112 -688 112
WIRE -608 112 -608 80
WIRE -480 112 -608 112
WIRE -720 144 -720 112
WIRE -240 144 -240 80
WIRE -720 240 -720 224
WIRE -416 240 -416 160
WIRE -416 240 -720 240
WIRE -240 240 -240 208
WIRE -240 240 -416 240
WIRE 624 240 624 80
WIRE 624 240 -240 240
WIRE -720 256 -720 240
FLAG -720 256 0
FLAG -192 48 D1
FLAG -688 112 V1
FLAG -80 80 D2
SYMBOL ind2 -592 0 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value 100uH
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0.001 Rpar=0 Cpar=0
SYMBOL ind2 -432 -112 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 100uH
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0.001 Rpar=0 Cpar=0
SYMBOL voltage -720 128 R0
WINDOW 3 33 81 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 0 33 33 Left 2
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL npn -480 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value 2SCR533P
SYMBOL res -624 96 M180
WINDOW 0 36 76 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 17K
SYMBOL LED -160 64 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 77 40 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL schottky -352 32 M90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D91
SYMATTR Value 1N5817
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL LED -64 64 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 106 36 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 32 64 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 77 40 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 128 64 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 106 36 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 224 64 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 77 40 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D5
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 320 64 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 106 36 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D6
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 416 64 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 77 40 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D7
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 512 64 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 106 36 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D8
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED -160 -128 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 77 40 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D9
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED -64 -128 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 106 36 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D10
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 32 -128 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 77 40 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D11
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 128 -128 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 106 36 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D12
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 224 -128 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 77 40 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D13
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 320 -128 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 106 36 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D14
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 416 -128 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 77 40 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D15
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL LED 512 -128 M90
WINDOW 0 -5 30 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 106 36 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D16
SYMATTR Value LXK2-PW14
SYMBOL cap -256 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 22uF
TEXT -552 -128 Left 2 !K1 L1 L2 1.00
TEXT -672 24 Left 2 ;Pot
TEXT -648 256 Left 2 !.tran 0 10m 5m startup
RECTANGLE Normal -496 80 -688 0 2
```