# LED brightness control with a potentiometer

Tags: led, potentiometer, led-driver, dimmer

Can we use these potentiometers to control LED brightness? 150mA current at 12  volts,  the LEDs are 5mm in series and parallel, keeping circuit simplicity and avoiding CC circuit. Did anyone use these pots as shown in the figure? Use only the potentimeters in which the wattage is very low. These are general purpose potentiometers.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: Thanks for the suggested edit on my LED flasher post. Some of the spelling changes you suggested were incorrect and another moderator rejected the edit BUT I looked at your suggestions and went over the post again and fixed a number of typos - some you had suggested plus others. The edit accept/reject system is not flexible so your good input was not officially noted - so, thanks. || Having got my attention - I looked at your posts and upvoted a few deserving ones, so you still got some credit as a result of the edit :-).

Comment: Edit reject and most other are not flexible, even asking questions,  unable to ask new questions like how much a led draws in 20 msec if its rated at 20mamp. Wanted to strobe at peak

Comment: You cannot ask questions because the system has a feature (that I dislike) that  stops new users asking more questions if they  have asked a series of very low score or negative score questions. The intention is that the user improvs these questions before more can be asked OR that they get some more "reputation" by answering some other questions. This can be a hard situation to get out of - as you are finding :-(.  || IF you can gain some reputation by answering a few questions the system will unlock your account. If this fails, message me again or flag this question for moderator attention.

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange! In my opinion, if you can, you should click the little green checkmark next to the answer by @PStechPaul and accept it as being your "accepted answer" because his circuit perfectly answers your question, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

These pots can do what you want but they need some help with more electronics. There are many ways of doing this, analog and PWM. You can purchase a PWM module for LEDs for probably less then you spend on the pots you have. Analog will work but it will give you a very narrow control range so PWM is by far better and more economical. Rather them make suggestions as to which is the best I suggest you search for "PWM LED module"

Answer (score 2):

What must be understood about using just a potentiometer (or rheostat) for LED brightness control, is that its power rating and resistance determine the maximum current it can safely handle. So the 10k device shown in the image might be 1 watt, that means that its maximum current is:

I = sqrt(P/R) = 10 mA

Also, there needs to be some "headroom" between the minimum supply voltage (in this case 12V) and the maximum voltage of the LED string for desired brightness (in this case limited by the 10mA maximum current). So for typical white LEDs with 3V forward voltage, only three can be connected in series, leaving 3 volts to be dropped by the potentiometer. 10 mA at 3V is a resistance of 300 ohms. For a 10k pot with 270 degrees of rotation, this resistance comprises only 8 degrees. To get 10% brightness at 1 mA, the shaft would be turned to get 3k resistance, or 80 degrees, and at minimum, you would have 300 uA, which is very dim.

However, adding a single transistor and a current limiting reference resistor, a practical circuit can be made:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo4IX4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the potentiometer set at 30%, the base of Q1 will be 3 volts, and the voltage on the emitter will be about 2.3 volts, corresponding to 46 mA through the LED string. The maximum current would be with the pot set at about 40%, which would cause Q1 to be saturated, with 3V on the emitter and 60 mA through the LEDs.

(edit) Here is an LTspice simulation that shows the effect of varying the 10k pot from 0 to 50%, with a 20 ohm resistor, and maximum current of 150 mA:

[image: LED String Brightness]

Comment: @HarshitaKapur - Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange!  In my opinion, if you can, you should click the little green checkmark next to this question and accept it as being your "accepted answer" because the above circuit perfectly answers your question, I believe.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD, you should post this comment in the OP's question.